# Wildcard SSL certificate with IIS webserver type Can it be used on Linux servers using Apache?

Tags: apache, configuration, ssl-certificate, iis-7, wildcard

I have a wildcard SSL Certificate with webserver type IIS 7 and later, if I use it for apache type can it be? and if it is reissued to the Apache web server type, will it affect the ssl that has been preconfigured in IIS?

Comment: This is more of a question on server administration. X509 certificates can be used with any web server, but you need to have its private key of a certificate and tools to convert to/from varied file format so as to follow the steps required by Apache.